# Update Account level fields through journey builder based on the response received from email sent to Lead?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, field-update, lead-conversion

We're using marketing cloud, integrated with sales cloud, to send emailers.

There are two objects, "Lead" & "Account". Both object have a field named "email_status".

Whenever a new Lead is created, a triggered email is sent and after 3 days based on the response, i.e. delivered or not, email_status is updated accordingly against Lead.

There are few cases where Lead is converted into Account within 3 days. How do I update such cases using same journey.

Comment: Why not use one of the Sales & Service Cloud activities?

Comment: I'm sending a email verification mail, if it's delivered to recipient, want to tag it verified in sales cloud, or otherwise tag bounce. I'm not sure how to do this using sales cloud activities.